# Mulder's neurological condition in "Biogenesis" and "The Sixth Extinction"

Tags: the-x-files

**What was the cause of Mulder's neurological condition in "Biogenesis", "The Sixth Extinction", and "The Sixth Extinction Part II: Amor Fati"?**

Was it his prior exposure to the black oil in "Tunguska" and "Terma"?  He was given the weak vaccine just prior to exposure at the end of "Tunguska", which seemed to effectively prevent his infection.  I recall Michael Kritschgau explaining a connection to Mulder's experience at Tunguska at some point in one of the three aforementioned episodes, but how does this square up with the vaccination?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Mulder was suffering from 'increased brain activity' and an onset of telepathy which was caused by 'reawkened' black oil that he infected with in the episode 'Tunguska' three years earlier.

Here's the breakdown:

[Biogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biogenesis_(The_X-Files))

> Mulder is being held in a padded cell and is displaying abnormal brain activity.

[The Sixth Extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Extinction_(The_X-Files))

> Kritschgau believes Mulder has alien induced mind reading abilities and injects him with a drug (phenytoin) to slow down his brain activity.

[The Sixth Extinction II: Amor Fati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Extinction_II:_Amor_Fati)

> Scully returns from Africa to discover Mulder in a coma induced by exposure to shards from an alien spaceship wreck

And,

> Kritschgau visits Scully and claims that Mulder's contact with the shard of an alien spaceship has reawakened the extraterrestrial black oil with which he was [infected three years previously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_(The_X-Files)); because he is infected with the virus, Mulder is proof of alien life

And,

> Mulder is revealed to be dreaming everything: in reality he is in a government facility being tended to by doctors while The Smoking Man and Fowley watch. The Smoking Man is preparing to have portions of Mulder's cranial tissue—which have been infected and activated because of the alien virus—implanted into himself. During the operation, The Smoking Man admits that he believes that Mulder has become an alien-human hybrid, and that by taking Mulder's genetic material he alone will survive the coming alien onslaught.

So, short answer, contact with the shards from the African spaceship has reawkened the black oil infection that has been hitherto dormant.